# Error 'you must supply a name when declaring a config resouce' when deploying a rails app to OpsWorks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef, opsworks

When moving a rails app from engine yard to OpsWorks, I am getting the following error:

```
Error executing action `deploy` on resource 'deploy[{{ app path }}]'
you must supply a name when declaring a config resouce
```

When deploying a rails app to ops works. The error goes on to say "

I have confirmed that my "custom json" is populating the `database.yml` file correctly.

Further details are given:

```
Resource Declaration:
deploy deploy[:deploy_to] do
  provider Chef::Provider::Deploy.const_get(deploy[:chef_provider])
  ..
```

The interesting thing is that in the following dump, there is a `params` list which includes

```
:name => nil
```

Which appears to be the problem. I have checked over all my forms in OpsWorks and every name field is populated. Beyond that, the custom JSON appears to be correct, as it is populating into the database.yml file. I am not sure what else to check from there.

Has anyone seen this issue before, or can anyone offer any thoughts on how I could pin down what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the old engine yard deploy scripts assume different parameters than what opsworks uses in its deploy scripts. The solution was to rewrite the deploy scripts removing the engine yard wrapper code.

Comment: Ran into the exact same problem trying out the migration from EngineYard. Thanks for posting your solution.

Comment: @rossta You are very welcome. I am happy that my travails were an aid to someone somewhere.